# Explain the output of program below?

Tags: c#, oop

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.print();

    }
}

class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class A
{
    public void print()
    {
        Employee emp = new Employee { Name = "1" };
        Func2(emp);

        Console.WriteLine(emp.Name);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private void Func2(Employee e)
    {
        Employee e2 = new Employee { Name = "3" };
        e = e2;

    }

}
```

After running the Above program, I got "1" as answer, which I'm not able to understand HOW? Can anyone explain, the answer according to me should be "3" 
-Thanks

But when I call Func1 method which is defined below:-

```
private void Func1(Employee e)
{
    e.Name = "2";
}
```

I get "2" as answer. Now if e was passed as Value type then how come it's giving me "2" as answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the bit that is getting you regarding `Func2`:

```
private void Func2(Employee e)
{
    Employee e2 = new Employee { Name = "3" };
    e = e2;
}
```

`Employee` is a reference type (a class), but the *reference* itself is passed by value - it is a *copy* of the reference.

You are then assigning to this copy a new reference, but the *original* reference (that was copied from) did not change. Hence, you are getting a `1`.

If you pass the *reference* itself by reference, you can modify it:

```
private void Func2(ref Employee e)
{
    Employee e2 = new Employee { Name = "3" };
    e = e2;
}
```

The above will produce `3`, as you expected.

---

Update, regarding your added `Func1`:

The reference is a copy, but is still pointing to the *same* object - you are changing the state of this object (setting the `Name` property), not the underlying object reference itself.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `Func2`, it passes a reference **by value**. Assigning to `e` inside the method does not change the value stored in `emp`, it just assigns a different value to the local variable `e`.

If you want to pass by reference use the `ref` keyword.

```
Func2(ref emp);

private void Func2(ref Employee e)
{
    // etc... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `func2` you are creating a new instance of employee and assigning a value to it. Where as in `func1` you are just modifying an already created instance and so the change is reflected back.

Comment: Yes I'm creating a new Instance in Func2, but, after changing the name property, I'm assigning this newly created instance to the already created instance, so that's why I was thinking it should reflect